Kernel param for SCTP socket buffer size missing in recent Docker Desktop's linuxkit
The net.sctp.sctp_rmem and net.sctp.sctp_wmem kernel parameters are missing in recent verions of Docker Desktops linuxkit. They are for tweaking SCTP socket read/write buffer sizes.
These params are crucial if you need large SCTP message sizes. Anybody knows what caused this and how do I bring them back?
I'm using Docker Desktop 4.36.0 for Macos Sequoia on an Apple Silicon chip.
